# Homogenous ODE $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac1{(y-4x-1)^2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve this homogeneous ODE:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac1{(y-4x-1)^2}$$
If there are any substitutions involved, what will they be?

Answer (score 1):

I would substitute $z = y - 4x - 1$. Then you get $$\frac{dz}{dx}= \frac{1}{z^2} - 4 = \frac{1 - 4z^2}{z^2}$$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: I am not dealing with partial DE's here, hence i can't substitute z for two variables.

Comment: @SohaibAli I know that this is not a partial DE. But you can of course do such a substitution. If you would write $y(x)$ it would make it much clearer.

Comment: i get your point now. Thanks @TheGeekGreek.

Answer (score 0):

$$y'(x)=\frac{1}{\left(y(x)-4x-1\right)^2}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Let $r(x)=y(x)-4x$, which gives $r'(x)=y'(x)-4$:

---

$$r'(x)+4=\frac{1}{\left(r(x)-1\right)^2}\Longleftrightarrow\int\frac{r'(x)}{\frac{1}{\left(r(x)-1\right)^2}-4}\space\text{d}x=\int1\space\text{d}x$$

Now, use:

1. Substitute $u=r(x)-1$ and $\text{d}u=r'(x)\space\text{d}x$:
   $$\int\frac{r'(x)}{\frac{1}{\left(r(x)-1\right)^2}-4}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{1}{\frac{1}{u^2}-4}\space\text{d}u=\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{1}{2u+1}\space\text{d}u-\frac{1}{8}\int\frac{1}{2u-1}\space\text{d}u-\frac{1}{4}\int1\space\text{d}u$$
2. $$\int1\space\text{d}x=x+\text{C}$$

So, we get:

$$\frac{\ln\left|2r(x)-1\right|-\ln\left|2r(x)-3\right|-4(r(x)-1)}{16}=x+\text{C}$$

Set $r(x)=y(x)-4x$ back:

$$\frac{\ln\left|2(y(x)-4x)-1\right|-\ln\left|2(y(x)-4x)-3\right|-4((y(x)-4x)-1)}{16}=x+\text{C}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the substitution
$$z=y-4x-1$$
This gives the transformered DE
$$\frac{dx}{dz} = \frac{z^2}{1-4z^2} $$
This leads to the integral
$$x=\int\frac{z^2}{1-4z^2}   dz$$
For this I used the substitution $$z=\frac{1}{2}sin(\theta)$$
From this,
$$dz=\frac{1}{2}cos\theta(d\theta)$$
$$x=\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{sin^2\theta}{1-sin^2\theta}dz =  \frac{1}{4}\int tan^2 \theta dz$$
Substituting dz in gives
$$x = \frac{1}{8}\int (sin^2 \theta)(sec \theta)d\theta $$
Using the identity $$sin^2\theta=1-cos^2\theta$$,
$$x=\frac{1}{8} \int(sec\theta - cos\theta)$$
$$x=\frac{1}{8}(ln(sec\theta+tan\theta)-sin\theta)+C$$
Substituting back $$\theta=\arcsin(2z)$$
Gives $$x=\frac{1}{8}(ln(sec(arcsin(2z))+tan(arcsin(2z)))-2z) + C$$
Now use the following expressions,
$$\theta=arccos((1-4z^2)^\frac{1}{2})$$ and $$\theta=arctan\frac{2z}{(1-4z^2)^\frac{1}{2}}$$
to eliminate the trigonometric functions.
$$x = \frac{1}{8}\left(ln\left(\frac{1+2z(1-4z^2)^\frac{1}{2}}{(1-4z^2)^\frac{1}{2}}\right)-2z\right) + C$$
From here you can substitute z back in and get a very messy general solution.